# $u_t + a(x) u_x = 0, u(x, 0) = f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ given an example of $a(x)$ for which the solution of the Cauchy problem is not unique.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following problem. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Consider the Cauchy problem, $u_t + a(x) u_x = 0, u(x, 0) = f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ given an example of an (unbounded) smooth $a(x)$ for which the solution of the Cauchy problem is not unique.

**I just tried a bunch of polynomials and exponentials but I can't seem to get an example of a PDE that gives a nonunique solution.**

Comment: Did you investigate $a(x) = x^2$ where the characteristic curves blow up in finite time?

Comment: You wrote : "I just tried a bunch of polynomials and exponentials". But for what function ? For function $a(x)$ ? For function $f(x)$ ? or for both ? Also it is written  : " given an example of an (unbounded) smooth $a(x)$ for which the solution of the Cauchy problem is not unique" . Why are you looking for an example since it is written that an example is given ? What exactly is asked to find in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the method of characteristics, $u\big(x(t), t\big)$ stays constant along the charactersitic curves defined as

\begin{align}
x'(t) &= a(x) \\
x(t_0) &= x_0
\end{align}

Thus you can only have a non-unique solution if the characteristics intersect.
An easy example for this would be

$$a(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \leq 0 \\ -1 & x \geq 0 \end{cases} $$

With solution
$$
x(t) = \begin{cases} t + x_0 & t + x_0 \leq 0 \\
0 & x = 0 \\
-t + x_0 & -t + x_0 > 0
\end{cases}
$$

Consider now $x_0^{(1)} = -1, x_0^{(2)} = 1$.
Clearly, at $t=1$ the solutions intersect and for general $f(x)$, $f(x_0^{(1)}) \neq f(x_0^{(2)})$.

Now for smooth (I assume you mean at least once continuously differentiable) $a(x)$ I cannot think of an example where the IVP has no unique solution.

However, it is relatively easy to construct $a(x)$ where solutions exists only on a finite time.
The standard example for this is $a(x) = x^2$ with characteristic curves
$$x(t) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_0} -t }$$
which clearly blow up for $t\to \frac{1}{x_0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Below, this isn't an answer to the question but a comment too large to be edited in the comments section.

The general solution of $u_t+a(x)u_x=0$ is $$u(x,t)=F\left(-t+\int \frac{dx}{a(x)}\right)$$ with arbitrary function $F$.

Condition $u(x,0)=f(x) \quad\implies\quad F\left(\int \frac{dx}{a(x)}\right)=f(x)$

Let $X(x)=\int \frac{dx}{a(x)}$ and it's inverse function $x=\Phi(X)$
$$F(X)=f\Big(\Phi(X)\Big)$$
We put $F(X)$ into the above general solytion where $X=-t+\int \frac{dx}{a(x)}$

The solution satisfying both the PDE and the condition is :
$$u(x,t)=f\left(\Phi\Big(-t+\int \frac{dx}{a(x)}\Big)\right)$$
For given functions $a(x)$ and $f(x)$ the function $\Phi$ is theoretically given but cannot always be expressed with elementary and standard special functions since $\Phi$ is the inverse function of an integral. Moreover $\Phi$ might be a multivalued function in some cases depending from the kind of function $a(x)$. Or in other cases  $\Phi$ might be a piecewise function.

What does mean "given an example of an (unbounded) smooth $a(x)$ for which the solution of the Cauchy problem is not unique" ? Is a multivalued function considered as an unique solution or a non-unique solution ? The wording of the question is somewhat ambiguous.